# Android Geocoder Address Type

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I'm  using the Android Geocoder to lookup a List of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) objects - so far so good.

I'm interested in the ["types"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) which is a property available using the service directly but does not appear to be available using the Android API. Is there a way to get to this using the Android Geocoder?